# Genymotion software itself not booting on windows 10 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, genymotion

Genymotion working fine till the afternoon at a sudden the emulator hanged, its quick common so I have closed the emulator and tried to open the emulator once again but it is not opening so I have decided to restart the Genymotion software. After restarting the Geymotion it is showing continuous booting but the software didn't start

What I tried

1. Restarting the system.
2. Reinstalling the Genymotion software.
3. Reinstalling the Genymotion software along with Oracle virtual box.[image: The Genymotion software struck here only]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simple Solution is Just Run Genymotion as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to purge, not just remove, Genymotion before reinstalling?
If not, see https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002815177-How-to-uninstall-Genymotion-Desktop-completely-purge-

Comment: I have followed the above steps but the Same problem occurring Julien And Thanks for the response

Comment: Could you generate logs and attach them here? If you can't do it from the UI, you can use gmtool (cf. https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002784898-How-to-get-Genymotion-Desktop-logs- ). Also, you should try to remove and reinstall VirtualBox with a different version (6.1.X or 6.0.X)

Comment: Hey Julien, Here is the log [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ECUtzgdT0k4NoZ9qK6UuhONNEUttrCB/view?usp=sharing)